# Mutable borrow + return within a loop

Tags: rust

I have a segment of Rust code which, simplified, looks something like this:

```
struct FooRef<'f>(&'f mut i32);

fn blah<'f>(f: &'f mut i32) -> FooRef<'f> {
    let mut i = 0;
    loop {
        let fr = FooRef(f);
        if i == *fr.0 {
            return fr;
        }
        i += 1;
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut f = 5;
    blah(&mut f);
}
```

[playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=24f19aa1d75bbd31cef6c5cc78b7c3e9&version=stable)

It doesn't compile:

```
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `*f` as mutable more than once at a time
  --> test.rs:6:25
   |
6  |         let fr = FooRef(f);
   |                         ^
   |                         |
   |                         second mutable borrow occurs here
   |                         first mutable borrow occurs here
...
12 | }
   | - first borrow ends here
```

If I understand this error, it's saying that `f` can be borrowed until the end of the function on one loop iteration, then borrowed again on a second iteration, which doesn't work.

This doesn't seem right to me; either `fr` goes out of scope (and thus is returned before it says) or it returns (and there's no subsequent borrow).

Is there any way to express this that will compile?

Comment: You will find a lot of duplicate of this problem, here the fix, https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=31b82f9856dfe3695468e1d350632b32&version=stable.

Comment: Hmm, that's not what I was hoping for. In my real logic, the equivalent of `FooRef(f)` does something non-trivial; I want to ensure that `FooRef::drop` runs when the `FooRef` goes out of scope. Is that really the only option?

Comment: You could declare the variable before the loop, I'm not fully qualified to know if there are other options. Maybe use RefCell. Maybe your [mcve] is too minimal to represent your situation ?

Comment: I couldn't find a dupe on SO but here's a discussion of the same issue: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/21906. It's a borrow checker limitation that should be fixed by [non-lexical lifetimes](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust-roadmap/issues/16) if that ever gets implemented.

Comment: @Stargateur to answer your question about my example, the difference between this and the real one is essentially ref-counting. The details don't seem that relevant to me, but if you really want them: I'm trying to make my own ffmpeg wrapper. This function is being passed a (wrapper around an) `AVPacket`, which gets filled by a call to `av_read_frame`. Once it's filled, the packet has a reference which must be released via `av_packet_unref`; `FooRef` does that. The loop is discarding packets that aren't of interest; there may be both audio and video packets, and I only want the video ones.

Comment: Here's the duplicate's answer [applied to your code](https://play.integer32.com/?gist=8017bb807514fdd410ebdbf9a8798b00&version=stable). TL;DR: you need to hold the compilers hand a little bit and be explicit about the moves of the mutable reference.